# Moment js :- Getting Unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, time, compare, momentjs

I'm trying to compare two dates using moment js but getting an unexpected output :-

```
var day1 = moment("24-01-2016 19:29","DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
var day2 = day1.add('m', 500);
document.writeln(day1.isBefore(day2,'minute'));
output : false (Expected to be true)
document.writeln(day1.isSame(day2,'minute'));
output : true (Don't know why)
```

I'm totally confused. It seems i'm missing something.

Comment: From the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/): "**Mutates the original moment** by adding time."

Comment: @Andreas so we need to make a clone of day1 ?

Comment: I think so. `var day2 = day1.clone().add("m", 500)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the manipulation methods (incl. `.add()`) will mutate the original object.

[`.add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/): 
***Mutates the original moment** by adding time.*

You will have to first clone `day1` and then manipulate this clone

```
var day2 = day1.clone().add("m", 500);
// or
var day2 = moment(day1).add("m", 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that using moment is creating an object. Since objects are passed by reference, both day1 & day2 are referring to the same object.

Therefore,

```
document.writeln(day1.isSame(day2,'minute'));
```

returns true.